# WPF: No Parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm trying to use a UserControl I did, but currently, I've an error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

The thing is... There is only one constructor, and it has no parameters.

Here is some code:

```
<DockPanel x:Class="Xms.SomePackage.NewLicenseWizard"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:wizard="clr-namespace:my.wizard.namepsace;assembly=My.Common.Assembly"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" LastChildFill="True">
    <wizard:Wizard> <-- Error is here -->
        <wizard:WizardPage>
            <wizard:WizardPage.ContentElement>
                <TextBlock>Page one</TextBlock>
            </wizard:WizardPage.ContentElement>
        </wizard:WizardPage>
    </wizard:Wizard>
</DockPanel>
```

The `Wizard` UserControl looks like this:

```
[ContentProperty("Pages")]
public partial class Wizard : UserControl, IView
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    //All the Dependencies Properties)]
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    internal WizardViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as WizardViewModel; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Wizard()
    {
        Pages = new ObservableCollection<WizardPage>();
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModelLocationProvider.AutoWireViewModelChanged(this);
        //[Some other initialization]
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I just removed the DependencyProperties.

So why is it thinking that I've no parameterless constructor?

(at runtime I've no issues)

**EDIT**
Here is the ViewModel bound to the Wizard UserControl:

```
internal class WizardViewModel : XmsViewModelBase
{
    #region public Properties
    public InteractionRequest<CloseWindowRequest> CloseWindowRequest { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand GoToPreviousPageCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand GoToNextPageCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand FinishCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand CancelCommand { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<WizardPage> Pages
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<WizardPage>>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
    public WizardPage CurrentPage
    {
        get { return GetValue<WizardPage>(); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(value);
            HandleCurrentPageChanged();
        }
    }
    public Boolean IsLastPage
    {
        get { return GetValue<Boolean>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public WizardViewModel()
    {
        Pages = new ObservableCollection<WizardPage>();
        //+Initialization of commands
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

     // All the methods related to the commands
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If there is a linked view model, can be the viewModel constructor the one that fails?

Comment: There is ViewModel, but it's instantiate by Prism(`ViewModelLocationProvider.AutoWireViewModelChanged(this);`). From the UserControl point of View, it can't know that this is a constructor.

Comment: I still thinking that is the autowire part that makes the exception, can you post the viewModel code?

Comment: @J4N Your class name is different in xaml and cs
NewLicenseWizard
and
Wizard

Comment: @netaholic NewLicenseWizard is the UserControl that will contains(and configure) the Wizard. These are two differents classes

Comment: @Kirenenko I added the code in the original question. I tried to put a `if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))`before doing the initialization  of the Wizard, it seems to work, but I'm not sure of what could cause this issue of having the constructor not correctly recognized

Comment: Are you sure that the `Wizard` class (both partial classes) is located in the namespace `My.Common.Assembly` which is indicated in your xaml? You left out the namespace part of the class definition of the `Wizard` class in the code you posted.

Comment: @Martin : NewLicenseWizard is in one Module, Wizard(xaml, code behind and ViewModel) are in the same namespace and package, I guarantee. (and my code work at running, my only issue is within the designer)

Comment: I suspect the error is because you are using `<DockPanel>` as your root element and frankly I have never seen such declaration. You can define all your controls in either a `Window` or a `Page`